# MySQL "LOAD DATA INFILE" query, issue with "TERMINATED BY"

Tags: mysql

I have an `hashes` table with 2 columns, `hash | plain`

And a text file looking like that:

```
acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8:foo
37b51d194a7513e45b56f6524f2d51f2:bar
4e99e8c12de7e01535248d2bac85e732:foo:bar
```

I'm trying to execute this query:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE hashes COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The issue is, for the hash `4e99e8c12de7e01535248d2bac85e732`, it will only insert `foo`, not `foo:bar`, because of `COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ':'`.

How can I make it "only split once" to fix this issue?

Comment: I think mysql doesn't support this. May write a script to extract and insert from file.

Answer (score 0):

You could load into a user variable and use a bit of string maniplulation.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(hash varchar(100),plain varchar(100));

LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' 
INTO TABLE t 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@var)
set   
        hash = substring_index(@var,':',1),
        plain = replace(@var,substring_index(@var,':',1),'')
;


select * 
from t;

+--------+----------+
| hash   | plain    |
+--------+----------+
| abc    | :def     |
| abc    | :ghi     |
| abc    | :def:ghi |
+--------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Note I have used \r\n to load this properly - you should test for your environment

Comment: Hello, I do not want the first `:` to be inserted, so I'd basically want `abc | def:ghi` instead of `abc | :def:ghi`. Thank you